# ActionBarSherlock action bar not visible on JellyBean

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, compatibility, android-actionbar-compat

I moved to ABS and it's fine on Gingerbread but action bar doesn't show up on ICS. WHy is that?

Manifest:

```
   <application
      android:name="MyApp"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
```

Comment: What's your target sdk?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are hiding the title bar in your app. Hiding the title bar will also remove any native action bars.

I'd search for (and remove) something like this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

The same goes for any XML:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Should be set to false. (Which should be default in the theme you are using)